# Display Sprite Image Only Within Bounds of it's Parent

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, parent-child, transparent

I want to be able to display an image which only show the parts of the image which are within the bounds of it parent. If the image extends outside it's parent's bounds, those part of the image will become transparent.

Just an example, but say I have a sprite which is 100 x 100 and a child sprite is added to this sprite and it is 200 x 200 and coloured blue, only 100 x 100 of the blue sprite will be displayed on the screen. This is what I'm hoping to do if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SKCropNode to achieve what you need:

```
let nodeToMask = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))

let mask = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blackColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))

let cropNode = SKCropNode()

cropNode.addChild(nodeToMask)
cropNode.maskNode = mask
cropNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(frame))

addChild(cropNode)
```

Here, you have:

1. `nodeToMask` object which is SKSpriteNode and represents the image you want to mask. You add it to the crop node as a child.
2. `cropNode` object which is container for the image you plan to mask.
3. you have an actual mask which is `SKSpriteNode` and you assign it to [maskNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKCropNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKCropNode/maskNode) property of a crop node.

For more details about SKCropNode check out [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKCropNode_Ref/index.html).